# How to get facebook profile picture thumbnail?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am able to get the album images fine from profile pictures, via this api call:

```
facebookModule.requestWithGraphPath("/"+albumId+"/photos", {
    fields : 'source,icon'
} [..]
```

However, I was wondering if there is a way to get the profile pic icons from facebook, or do I have to resize the source image manually in javascript. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question.

Answer (score 1):

use the FB.api and add field `picture.width`

```
FB.api('/me',{
    fields: 'name,id,picture.width(100).height(100)'
  }, function (response) {
    if (response && !response.error) {
     console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
http://graph.facebook.com/[replace with name or id]/picture
```

For example: http://graph.facebook.com/zuck/picture

Comment: Which picture does it crop - does it just crop their main profile pic?

Comment: @bobo2000 - That is the user's profile pic (50x50px).

Comment: Thanks Derek, is there way I could get it for specific photos?

Answer (score 0):

Along with source and icon, graph api will also return Id of that picture. You can use this id for specific picture like thi

```
http://graph.facebook.com/{id}/picture?type=album
```

In case you got question mark photo, try this

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{id}/picture?type=album&access_token={User accessToken}
```

Remember to use https when sending accesstoken with query string.

In type you can also write thumbnail or normal.